# How to compile with --bin option in solcjs?

Tags: contract-deployment, solc, bytecode, compilation, solcjs

I want to compile using `--bin` option because I want to get to see the `bytecode` of the compilation.

Using `solc` I know it is something like this: `solc --bin`

How can I achieve this using `solcjs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you run this command using `solcjs` is the following:

`solcjs --bin --include-path ../node_modules/ --base-path . MyERC20.sol`

You need to specify `include-path` to tell the compiler where you store external contracts and libraries (in this case for `open-zeppelin`).

**Note**: To make `--include-path` work, you also need to add a non-empty `--base-path`. In this case, you can just go `.` to tell the compiler you want to use the exact same directory you are at.